# How to include a salted password in spring-boot security with JWTAuthenticationFilter/JWTTokenizer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, hash

i am currently working with a frontend-backend-system consisting of a questionnaire which users can answer. I implemented argon2 as hashing algorithm to generate a salted hash from the users password to save together with the users personal questionnaire results, so only the user him-/herself can access his/her personal results.

Now, a user can log into his account with username+password, and the spring-boot backend uses spring security with JWTAuthenticationFilter and JWTTokenizer. Unfortunately, i am very new to this and can't figure out how to make the user-result-mapping available to the user when he/she logs in.

My thoughts are these: The User answers a questionnaire, the results are send to the backend, and then argon2 creates a salted hash from his/her passwort and saves it with the result.

Now, if the user logs into the system again, i can't use encode() from the argon2PasswordEncoder again, since it would generate a new salt which doesn't match the salted hash already saved with his result.

A person from our team advised me to adjust the JWTAuthenticationFilter/JWTTokenizer so my key is in it as a "claim", to adjust the JWTAuthorizationFilter to decode a custom AuthenticationToken which should include a field for my key and then "cast it in the service 'Authentication' to CustomAuthenticationToken and read the key".

But i am not able to figure out what he means. Where do i get the salted hash from the result-mapping from? I can't just encode the password again with argon2, because as said, it will generate a new salt! And i have no idea what really to adjust in the AuthenticationFilter/Tokenizer/AuthorizationFilter.

Suppose we have a Result-Entity with a field "userHash" which saves the salted argon2-hash of the user to whom this Result belongs. Saving the Result is not really implemented yet, since i don't know how, how i should save the result, since i can't do "get result from frontend, generate argon2 hash from user password, save it with the result" every time, since as already said, it generates a new salt every time.

So my question is: When do i create the salted hash, how do i handle it so we always have the very same salted hash for a user when he/she logs in? What does my colleague mean with his advice?

For reference, our attemptAuthentication-Method in the JWTAuthenticationFilter looks like this:

```
@Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws AuthenticationException {
        UserLoginDto user = null;
        try {
            user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), UserLoginDto.class);
            Authentication token;
            if (user.loginKey() != null) {
                token = new LoginKeyAuthenticationToken(user.loginKey());
            } else {
                if (user.usernameOrEmail() == null || user.password() == null) {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("Username/E-Mail and password may not be null.");
                }
                token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    user.usernameOrEmail().toLowerCase(),
                    user.password()
                );
            }

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong API request or JSON schema", e);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            if (user != null && user.usernameOrEmail() != null) {
                LOGGER.error("Unsuccessful authentication attempt for user {}", user.usernameOrEmail());
            }
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

JWTTokenizer, getAuthToken():

```
    public String getAuthToken(String user, List<String> roles) {
        byte[] signingKey = securityProperties.getJwtSecret().getBytes();
        String token = Jwts.builder()
            .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(signingKey), SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
            .setHeaderParam("typ", securityProperties.getJwtType())
            .setIssuer(securityProperties.getJwtIssuer())
            .setAudience(securityProperties.getJwtAudience())
            .setSubject(user)
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + securityProperties.getJwtExpirationTime()))
            .claim("rol", roles)
            .compact();
        return securityProperties.getAuthTokenPrefix() + token;
    }
```

Any advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72545570/4778343), maybe it will give you an idea what your teammate meant by including a custom claim. The only difference is that you'll need to adjust you `getAuthToken` method to pass the hash/key (however you call it), and to return your custom implementation of `JwtAuthenticationToken` which would have the hash/key from token.